# Can't scroll backward using UIAutomator2

Tags: appium, ui-automation

I am trying to scroll backward using the below code snippet but it throws error

- code snippet

  ```
  try {

      getTLDriver().findElements(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).setAsVerticalList().flingToBeginning(5);"));
  }
  catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```
- Error:

  ```
  org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Could not parse expression `new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).setAsVerticalList().flingToBeginning(5)`: Last method called on a UiScrollable object must return a UiObject object
  ```

Someone kindly help on it

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `TouchAction` to perform scrolling in Android, for example:

```
Dimension screenSize = driver.manage().window().getSize();
TouchAction action = new TouchAction((PerformsTouchActions) driver);
action.press(point(screenSize.width / 2, screenSize.height / 2))
   .waitAction()
   .moveTo(point(screenSize.width / 2, screenSize.height / 4))
   .release()
   .perform();
```